# How to replace " for ' in all csv files in one directory?

Tags: ruby

I need to replace " for ' in all csv files in one directory. I wonder if there is either

- nice one line piece of code to do that or
- if I use the `fastest` way to solve what I do

My code is

```
files = Dir["*.csv"]

files.each do |file_name|
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| 
    file.puts File.read(file_name).gsub('"', "'")
  }
end
```

### update

- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
- I prefer ruby only solution

Comment: You might have trouble if any of the files are much larger than the available memory on the system -- is that the case?

Comment: Hmmm, the csv files are test results files. I believe that all of them will be only little files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the files in place like so:

```
ruby -pi~ -e "gsub(/\"/, \"'\")" *.csv
```

Comment: put it inside backticks and use full paths.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you. Any idea if I can disable the backup thing?

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't see a way to disable it but theres always: `rm *~`

Comment: That's what I do :-) Hoped there will be clean solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it is asking you to call an external script (yes, it is ruby but external non the less) instead of using ruby.

How about:

```
def inplace_edit(file, bak, &block)
    old_argv = Array.new(ARGV)
    old_stdout = $stdout
    ARGV.replace [file]
    ARGF.inplace_mode = bak
    ARGF.lines do |line|
        yield line
    end
    ARGV.replace old_argv
    $stdout = old_stdout
end

my_files_array.each do |file|
    inplace_edit file, '.bak' do |line|
        STDOUT.puts "[Debug] #{line}"
        line = line.gsub(/search1/,"replace1")
        line = line.gsub(/search2/,"replace2")
        print line
    end
end
```

If you don't want to create a backup of every file then change '.bak' to ''.

Comment: Very good point and actually using 1ruby -pi~ -e "gsub(/\"/, \"'\")" *.csv` changes attributes of the csv files. Using your code I can handle that too.

Comment: Changing file attributes was one of the things that led me to search for a solution to do inplace editing in ruby. Also when you handle large files, reading a whole file into memory is not a good idea. Another reason to go for the inplace editing.

Answer (score 1):

Windows or a *nix system? If you're on something with `sed`, let it do what it's designed to do:

```
sed "s/\"/'/" < file_to_fix > updated_file
```

`sed` is used for similar tasks constantly and is blindingly fast. I wouldn't embed it in a Ruby script at all, but instead would use it at the command-line.